# How to remove wires from thermostat without screws

Tags: wiring, thermostat

How do I remove the wires from thermostat without screws holding the wires **or** any apparent hole to push and loosen the wires.
Picture below shows the wires:

[image: wiring]

Comment: A model number might help. The circuit board number AU7818 doesn't produce any useful results, but ICM Thermostat manuals are definitely available for some models.

Comment: lift the latch handles

Comment: I know they are low voltage wires, but those wires don't look too good... Make sure to prevent them from shorting? Currently they are spread far enough apart on the points where the insulation is damaged, but if that's not the case in your new thermostat, wrap them with some electrical tape or so. (White and red wire.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

One possibility is gently tugging on a wire while pressing in the button below the wire. The wire would come free and then the button would move out as the force on the button was relaxed.

Here’s a screen capture from a manufacturer’s video of this or similar product:

[image: phoenix tool free terminal block cutaway screen capture]

Comment: Something like that, because the buttons are all "down" where there are wires and "up" where there are no wires.

Comment: That is how they work. Video: https://youtu.be/1sulcXVK4t0

Answer (score 10):

That is very easy.  Just push in on the little tabs that are in place of the screws while pulling on the wires until they release.  As you can see, the sockets with wires attached have lower tabs than the ones with no wires.  That is because of the pinch mechanism inside of the sockets that is set up so that when the tabs are depressed enough, it allows the wires to be moved in and out. And when released, they pinch down, on watever is in the socket; if there is a wire there, it will be gripped.